# Linq Lambda - Most viewed page

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-4, pagedlist

I have a C# MVC4 web app that I'm trying to figure out the linq statement for. (Lambda if possible)

I have two tables, Hits and Posts. Hits tracks all the visits to every page on the site. Posts are like blog entries. When a user visits a Post, the PostId gets recorded in the Hit table.

Tables:

**Hits**
HitId, Url, PostId

**Posts**
PostId, PostDate, etc

A category of the site is 'Most Viewed', which will show a list of Most Viewed Posts descending by hits.

Lastly, I am using IPagedList, so keep in mind the final list needs to be Ordered.

What I've tried:

```
    var postCount = 
    _db.Posts.Join(_db.Hits, posts => posts.PostId, hits => hits.PostId, (posts, hits) => new { posts, hits })
    .GroupBy(num => num.posts.PostId)
    .OrderByDescending(gp => gp.Count())
    .Select(g => g.Key).ToList();

   var results = _db.Posts.Where(p => postCount.Contains(p.PostId));
   const int pageSize = 5;
   var pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
   return View(results.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
```

So the postCount is a list of PostId ordered by MostViewed, which is what I want. However since I'm using IPagedList, I get this error:

```
    The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'.
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

## EDIT

Thanks for anyone trying to help.

If I add .ToList():

```
    var results = _db.Posts.Where(p => all2.Contains(p.PostId)).ToList();
```

This resolves the error, but it still loses the order that postCount has. It's now just sorted by the PostId.

Maybe there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you just call `OrderBy` after the `Where`?

Comment: do you have `Hits` collection in each post in EF?

Comment: Can you show your call to PagedList?

Comment: Joey - Because postCount is already ordered by the Most Viewed. If I call it again then it won't be ordered by most viewed.

Comment: cadrell0 - I added the IPagedList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code looks awfully complicated. You can reduce that to *one* query by simply sorting the posts by their hit count, like this:

```
var results = from post in _db.Posts
              join hit in _db.Hits
              on post.PostId equals hit.PostId
              group hit by post into g
              orderby g.Count() descending
              select g.Key;

return View(results.ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 5));
```

This will translate to something like this:

```sql
SELECT Post.PostId, Post.PostDate, Post.Whatever, ..., COUNT(*) C
    FROM Post
    INNER JOIN Hit ON Post.PostId = Hit.PostId
    GROUP BY Post.PostId, Post.PostDate, Post.Whatever, ...
    ORDER BY C DESC
    OFFSET @offset ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @pageSize ROWS ONLY
```

Also, by adding `.ToList()` to your query, it will fetch everything from your database and do the filtering in memory, which might be much slower, depending on the connection between the server and the database.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following:

```
var results = _db.Posts.Join(_db.Hits, posts => posts.PostId, hits => hits.PostId, (posts, hits) => new { posts, hits })
    .GroupBy(num => num.posts)
    .OrderByDescending(gp => gp.Count())
    .Select(g => g.Key)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Joey - Appreciate the help. Nuffin's answer worked great.